# Java Spring data in MultiTenant architecture/PaaS SAP Hana Cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant, sap-cloud-platform

I'm feeling frustrated with my knowledge of spring and java, I hope someone can help me :)

I read the documentation of spring and searched for examples of how to implement multi tenancy in [hanacloud platform](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-9OTCw9rVAhWCiZAKHSk9CSAQFggyMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcloudplatform.sap.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGSMQpo-RSeee-1NuWFxV9zfP1BFw) but no one using spring data/eclipseLink ...

I really don't know how it is the life cycle of objects in framework and how to correctly configure in order to isolate the tenants in spring

The multi tenant strategy adopted was column descriptor to isolate the tenants, this column is described in superclass mapped in child entities...

Each consumer client is identified by url and can be accessed with this [API](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/a8f2255658ba4cbfb3ec3ab0f928f360.html), I've created a route to test the tenant id and the tenant id is different for each URl, which means the subscriptions to my applications its ok...

But the spring data don't isolate the data, i guess he is not creating the entity manager and repositories based in tenant id of consumers and create based in tenant id of provider, the ideia is create only one persistency unit and the data source separate the data based in the column descriptor,

The tenant's ids are generated by the system and its not possible create additional persistency units, they are created in the moment of subscription...

Here's the questions

- About the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, when he is called in stack ?
- It's possible to create one entity manager for each tenant id based in request ?

my configuration class to set datasource

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "neo" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceNeoConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();

    DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    try {
        lef.setDataSource(jndiDataSource());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
    properties.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_LEVEL, "FINE");
    properties.setProperty("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-tables");
// eclipselink.tenant.id is column the identifier in mapped class
// @TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", contextProperty = "eclipselink.tenant.id", length = 36)
    properties.setProperty("eclipselink.tenant.id", TenantHolder.getTenant());

    lef.setPackagesToScan("com.strongit.models");
    lef.setJpaProperties(properties);
    lef.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lef;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

  return transactionManager;
}
}
```

The springBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = AppNameApplication.class, entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
public class AppNameApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AvaliacaoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(AvaliacaoApplication.class);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: It's good that you show some code, but can you describe the problem you're trying to solve? I mean the business problem, not the technical one.

Comment: Hi Sarkar,
Each tenant cannot see the data from other tenants,

Comment: @MuriloMonteiro i hope you would have gone through this article https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation  . what is the strategy you are trying here ?

Comment: This will also help you to achieve it http://stuartingram.com/2016/10/02/spring-boot-schema-based-multi-tenancy/. The only change is implementation provider in your case is eclipselink

Comment: Hello @Barath, 

I'm using Discriminator field, this article references hibernate and I am using eclipseLink, can I mix eclipselink and hibernate ?

the classes CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, MultiTenantConnectionProvider described in this article use hibernate, if I can use, how can I create the entity manager per request and mix with the spring data to use the repositories?

Thanks for your response !!

Comment: Don't combine both. Chance is that you will be faced with more problems than you are facing now. My advice is that you should go with either database per tenant or schema per tenant strategy. Discriminator field strategy is really a pain with lots of cons. Usually not for first timers or beginners. Also more important is whenever you're working with any web framework of choice, use their default third party frameworks so you can easily find help when needed. For instance, Spring's default ORM framework is Hibernate and that's what most Spring-based web application developers are using.

Comment: Hi, @Perry...

The only strategy available for this PaaS is column descriptor in the selected plan from my company, which has only one java instance, one database and one schema...

Also, i choosed EclipseLink because accordingly with Hibernate documentation they don't support the column descriptor multi tenancy...

It's possible create entity managers based in a filters and use in repositories ?